# Making Spotify controller with C#

Tags: c#, controller, spotify

I am trying to make a windows application with C# that has buttons to control Spotify (externally), I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459162/user32-api-custom-postmessage-for-automatisation) code but what it does is that it uses the windows shortcuts (for example the Volume down makes the whole windows volume lower and not the Spotify volume), is there any other way to control the Volume and so on that are inside Spotify?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how one app I used to use does it. I haven't used it in a while, so I'm not sure if it is still functional behavior.

https://code.google.com/p/spotifycontrol/source/browse/trunk/SpotifyControl/Controllers/ControllerSpotify.vb#138

Comment: If you're using a handle to the Spotify application window, then this is the solution, sending ctrl-up/down keyboard messages to the app.  You should be able to translate the VB.NET code to C# fairly trivially.  If that is not the technique you're employing, this is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the Player object does indeed say that you can set volume as a float from 0.0 to 1.0.

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/f19ff300f8.html

It's possible, but you're only allowed to change the volume if your app initiated the playback that's occurring.

Comment: This is the wrong link I guess, but I don't see how it's possible to change the Spotify volume in C# to a value between 0.0 and 1.0